# "I see myself as" with personal names of well-known individuals

Tags: articles, proper-nouns

I'm not sure how to use articles when using personal names of well-known characters in this particular case.
For example it would be "I see myself as a nice person" or "I see myself as the flood control specialist". How should I use it with the proper names/fictional characters eg. Pope, Rambo, Chandler (meaning the character from Friends). Also what happens if something is added to the noun eg. "Rambo on vacation", "Chandler without friends".

Comment: Why would "I see myself as X" be any different to the way you refer to X in other contexts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the top of my head, I'd construct your examples in the following way:

- I see myself as the Pope.
- I see myself as Pope Benedict XII.
- I see myself as Rambo (on vacation).
- I see myself as Chandler without friends.

To my ears, *Rambo on vacation* grates. I might rather *I see myself as Rambo when on vacation.* But then it's unclear who's on vacation and where and when I see myself as Rambo.